# Getting all data out of models class, using views, onto a template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Coming out of the crash course book and trying to put things into practice.  The problem is the Django instructional did not cover multiple data points per class.

Below is the models, views, and the template.  I know the problem is the class, but I'm not finding the best way to return all the class data in a way the views def will pull it in.

(models.py)

```py
class PropData(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    prop = models.ForeignKey(Prop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_purchased = models.DateField()
    city = models.TextField(max_length=75)
    state = models.TextField(max_length=25)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
```

(views.py)

```py
def prop(request, prop_id):
    prop = Prop.objects.get(id=prop_id)
    propdata = prop.propdata_set.all()
    context = {'prop': prop, 'propdata': propdata}
    return render(request, 'propSheets/property.html', context)
```

(property.html)

```py
<p>Property: {{ prop }}</p>

<p>City: {{ propdata.city }}</p>
```

Of course, `propdata.city` returns nothing.  What do I need to add/change so I can output querysets to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `propdata` is a set of all the `PropData` objects, and so you could iterate over them to get each associated city. Try the following

```
{% for pd in propdata %}
    <p>City: {{ pd.city }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect, and painfully obvious now.  I'm coming from 15yrs in a different language, so I have relearn some new rules and unlearn some.